# Generating Time Slots using Moment Js

Tags: javascript, loops, momentjs, timeslots

I have Object structured like this

```
var x = {
    nextSlot: 30,
    breakTime: [
        ['11:00', '14:00'], ['16:00', '18:00']
    ],
    startTime: '8:00',
    endTime: '20:00'
}
```

**I want to geneate time slots , starting from startTime till endTime. But i dont want to consider breakTime in timeslot.
Output should be**

```
['08:00','08:30','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30','19:00','19:30']
```

I implemented my own logic. But that works on;y for the breaktime array of length 1.

```
// Check whether the startTime is less than endTime
while (moment(x.startTime, ['HH:mm']).format('HH:mm') < moment(x.endTime, ['HH:mm']).format('HH:mm')) {
    for (let i = 0; i < x.breakTime.length; i++) {
        // if startTime is greater then breakTime[i][0], and if starttime is less then breaktime[i][1], 
        //just add nextSlot to starttime 
        if (moment(x.startTime, ['HH:mm']).format('HH:mm') >= moment(x.breakTime[i][0], ['HH:mm']).format('HH:mm') && moment(x.startTime, ['HH:mm']).format('HH:mm') < moment(x.breakTime[i][1], ['HH:mm']).format('HH:mm')) {
            x.startTime = moment(x.startTime, ['HH:mm']).add(x.nextSlot, 'm').format('HH:mm');
        } else {
        //otherwise, push the time to slot array and then increment it by nextSlot 
            slots.push(moment(x.startTime, ['HH:mm']).format('hh:mm'));
            x.startTime = moment(x.startTime, ['HH:mm']).add(x.nextSlot, 'm').format('HH:mm');
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work if i add one more array element to `breakTime`.

Comment: Please add code comments on what your logic is trying to do.

Comment: updated it with comments

Comment: What is the logic of the output ? `11:00` is a break time but not in the output. `14:00` is a break time and is in the output. `16:00` is a break time but not in the output. `17:00` is not a break time and not in the output. `18:00` is a break-time but `17:30` and `18:00` are in the output. Please describe your logic here

Comment: breakTime `['11:00', '14:00 ']`, it means, from `11:00 to 13:30`, its a break time. `14:00` is not break (its end of break ). Same way another array too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
var x = {
    nextSlot: 30,
    breakTime: [
        ['11:00', '14:00'], ['16:00', '18:00']
    ],
    startTime: '8:00',
    endTime: '20:00'
};

var slotTime = moment(x.startTime, "HH:mm");
var endTime = moment(x.endTime, "HH:mm");

function isInBreak(slotTime, breakTimes) {
    return breakTimes.some((br) => {
      return slotTime >= moment(br[0], "HH:mm") && slotTime < moment(br[1], "HH:mm");
  });
}

let times = [];
while (slotTime < endTime)
{
  if (!isInBreak(slotTime, x.breakTime)) {
     times.push(slotTime.format("HH:mm"));
  }
  slotTime = slotTime.add(x.nextSlot, 'minutes');
}

console.log("Time slots: ", times);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear that!!