# How to format dates in Javascript date object and work with setting intervals between them?

Tags: javascript, date, object

I am making a scheduling application. The requirement is the user enters two time frames and the application should divide it into intervals of 20 with 10 minutes break in between. For instance, if I enter 15:15-17:15, it should give me slots like: ['15:15', '15:35', '15:45', '16:55'].

**Errors I am facing:** The approach I am using works fine for setting intervals but unable to give 10 minute break in between. My output gives ["15:15", "15:35", "15:55", "16:15", "16:35", "16:55", "17:15"]. Further if I enter the end time as 17:05, the result still gives the final count as 17:15.

Lastly if the above two issues are resolved I would be grateful if somebody can tell me how would I format the array such that I can the result as: [ '15:15-15:35', '15:45-16:55']. TIA

```
    let date1 = new Date(2020, 8, 20, 15, 15);
    let date2 = new Date(2020, 8, 20, 17, 05);
    let slots = []
    if(date1 < date2){
      console.log((date2.getHours()*60 - date1.getHours()*60)/20)
      for(var i = 0; date1 < date2; i=20)
      {
        date1.setMinutes(date1.getMinutes()+i)
        slots.push(date1.getHours() + ':' + date1.getMinutes());
      }
      console.log(slots)
    }
    else{
      console.log('End time should be greater than start time')
    }
```

Comment: You should look into MomentJs https://momentjs.com/ library to help with date and times.
See if this post solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123653/generating-time-slots-using-moment-js

Comment: The solution provided in the link does not address my usecase :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const dateToString = date => date.getHours() + ':' + (date.getMinutes() + '').padStart(2, '0')

const date1 = new Date(2020, 8, 20, 15, 15);
const date2 = new Date(2020, 8, 20, 17, 05);

function getIntervals(date1, date2) {
    date1 = new Date(date1.getTime()) // so we don't mutate date1

    const intervalLength = 20, breakLength = 10, intervals = []
    let interval

    while (date1 < date2) {
        interval && intervals.push(interval)

        interval = [intervalLength, breakLength].map(len => {
            const str = dateToString(date1)
            date1.setMinutes(date1.getMinutes() + len)
            return str
        }).join('-') // - separator
    }

    return intervals
}

console.log(getIntervals(date1, date2))
```

`dateToString` converts a Date object into an hh:mm format, padding the minute component with zeroes if necessary. To get the intervals, we step through by alternating time lengths of intervalLength and breakLength and push each generated interval to our array. We then return the interval.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do the first part. I have now added info about how the answer works

Comment: This works really well just that why isn't it considering the last interval i.e 16:35-17:05?

Comment: Replace date1 <= date2 to include the last interval; the loop is just terminating early

Answer (score 0):

The code in the OP doesn't seem to be dividing the time correctly or allowing for the intervals between periods.

The time between the two dates needs to be broken into *n* periods with *n-1* 10 minute breaks in between. Subtracting one date from the other will give the time difference in milliseconds, then it needs to be divided that into the required periods and intervals, e.g.

```js
/**
 * @param {Date} start - start date and time
 * @param {Date} end - end date and time
 * @param {number} periods - number of periods
 * @param {number} interval - interval between periods in minutes
 * @returns {Array} array of perids with interval gap between
 *   in format ['HH:mm - HH:mm', ...]
 */
function getSlots(start, end, periods, interval) {
  // Function to format period timestamp
  function f(d) {
    return ('' + d.getHours()).padStart(2, '0') + ':' + ('' + d.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
  }
  let slots = [];
  let diff = end - start;
  if (diff < 0) return 'End must be after start';
  // Get length of interval in ms
  let intLength = interval * 6e4;
  // Get total length of intervals in ms
  let intTotal = (periods - 1) * intLength;
  // Get length of each period in ms
  let periodLength = (diff - intTotal) / periods;
  
  // Generate periods
  for (let e, s = new Date(start), i = periods; i > 0; i--) {
    // Copy start to get end and add length of period
    e = new Date(+s + periodLength);
    // Write period to slots array
    slots.push(f(s) + '-' + f(e));
    // Increment s to start of next period
    s.setMilliseconds(s.getMilliseconds() + periodLength + intLength);
  }
  return slots;
}

let date1 = new Date(2020, 8, 20, 15, 15);
let date2 = new Date(2020, 8, 20, 17,  5);

console.log(getSlots(date1, date2, 2, 10));
```

Note that this entirely fills the time allowed, there is no interval at the ends. Also, times are truncated to whole minutes, so may appear to not have exactly the same number of minutes or be equal.